# How to build an exact matching regex?

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-group

I need to parse certain github image tags which are of the form 
`service-pr-07`
`service-abc1234` 
`service-master-latest`

I was using regex `/^#{service_name}-/` to find out the relevant data but this fails since the new tags are of the form 
`service-core-pr-99` , `service-core-abc345` etc.
 The old regex will return the `service-core` results also. What should I use?

Comment: What is `service_name` defined as?

Comment: In my code is just a user-defined value so there is no restriction on the name so the same name can be appended with a hypen and other text to create a new service name eg: user can giver test, test-core, test-frontend

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `pattern = r'^service'`? That will match the first three forms you want and the `service-core` forms too.

Comment: i don't want it to match the serice-core forms since their value is got from the user so if  a user passes service i only return the service- results not the service-core results